Oven/microwave combo will not work
So we had a Jennair wall oven microwave combo when we moved into our house and it worked great for several years. Suddenly they quit. If I open the microwave the lights flash on and off but it won't turn on. We have an extended warranty company send a tech out. He checked and replaced the control panel. Same problem existed. They sent an electrician out. He verified wiring, votage, and ground. No change and he recommended replacing the combo unit. They replaced the oven/microwave combo. Nothing changed. They said they could not do anything else until the warranty on the new appliance expired.
Someone had mentioned if there was a loose "lug", it could cause the problem. I have no idea where this "lug" would be and or if it's something I could check and tighten myself. I know the combo unit is direct wired into the circuit. Meaning there is no plug in for it. Breakers have been replaced with no change. I feel like it's something with in the breaker box because we also have an issue with a circuit that controls some of our outside lighting. I suspect these maybe inter-related. Any advise would be great.

Can you take measurements of the oven circuit at the panel while trying to run the oven?

If they replaced the unit, then the problem should be in something that was not replaced.  This can be with the wires connecting the oven to the breaker and/or the panel itself.  With a second circuit affected also, then posting pictures of the panel will help.  A licensed electrician should have checked everything, including the panel.
